# Download OSM tiles footprints as a layer

Tags: openstreetmap, layers, tiles, download

Is it possible to download a shape layer (or similar) with the OSM tile bounds from somewhere? Not the actual tiles, but only their polygon representations (for example-some area have about `n` tiles in zoom 17 and these are `n` polygons in a layer with x,y and zoom number as attributes)?

It's important to know how to get the tile names and footprints (in different scales between 7 and 17 zoom level) in a bounding box. I read a lot and nowhere was explained or given info as an opportunity to get some layer or WFS or similar data protocol...

Comment: one thing you need to be aware of: **for zoom level 17 alone** there are **17.179.869.184** (**+17 billion**; 2^17 * 2^17) tiles for the 'whole' planet (EPSG:3857)! even for an area the size of Germany we are talking about 25.000.000 tiles at zoom level 17! check [this](https://tools.geofabrik.de/calc/#type=geofabrik_standard&bbox=3.340796,47.593157,13.173805,55.256609) site for the numbers behind your idea. apart from that, it's rather trivial to calculate the bounds dynamically for a bbox within a function; follow the links [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).